how i can set boxshadow as a background in DIV
I'm working on a card and I want to add a box shadow behind a DIV to be like a background but after I set it up, it shows a white background on <h1> </h1> and <h3> </h3> like this:


How can I fix it?
<div className="[box-shadow:6px_-51px_182px_0px_rgba(19,52,255,0.86)]">
     <h3 className="text-[16.6px] font-normal text-[#575757] ">
     Vous payez
     </h3>
     <h1 className="text-[#000000] font-bold text-[44.28px] ">
     7750.00 <span className="text-[32px]">MAD</span>
     </h1>
</div>


You can use your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being set on those elements and where it comes from.
